# Pointing PHP Generated Text to Google Free Web Fonts

Tags: php, google-webfonts

Can some one let me know how I can use google web fonts for creating text captcha?

```
<?php
  $img          = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
  $bgColor      = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
  $netColor     = imagecolorallocate($img, 185, 185, 185);
  $txtColor     = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
  imagefill($img, 0, 0, $bgColor);
  imagettftext($img, 22, 0, 50 ,45, $txtColor,"Bedizen.ttf","Expert" ); 
  header("Content-type:image/png");
  imagepng($img);
  imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

As you can see from above code I am using a font file to render the text but is there any way to navigate to one of Google free web fonts?
Thanks

Comment: as with almost anything that has a url: you can download it as a file and just use it locally.

Comment: I don't think you can specify a URL for `imagettftext()`. [This guy wrote a class](http://bililite.com/blog/2012/06/04/using-imagettftext-with-off-site-font-urls/) that downloads files for use locally, but Marc B's solution is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that stumbles across this question (as I did) - this is do-able.  As Marc commented, you need to download the font from Google Fonts, upload to your webserver and include it that way.

I needed to include the full path to the font eg:

```
imagettftext($img, 22, 0, 50 ,45, $txtColor,"/path/to/webroot/fonts/Downlo-Bold.ttf","Expert" );
```